# Replacing 'this' with another object of the same kind

Tags: javascript, object

So I have my own `Bicycle` constructor (simple example):

```
function Bicycle (wheels, steer) {
  this.wheels = 2 + wheels;
  this.steer = wheels/steer;
}

Bicycle.prototype = {
  steer: function () {
    // do something
  },

  replace: function () {
    var bicycles = generateRandomBicycles();
    bicycles.sort(function (a, b) {
      return b.score - a.score;
    });

    this = bicycles[0];
  }
};
```

Pay attention to the `replace` function. I'm doing something similar to this, but i'm actually running a small genetic algorithm that should replace the current bicycle with a better one.

I'm aware that I could simply do:

```
this.wheels = bicycles[0].wheels;
this.steer = bicycles[0].steer;
```

But is there any smarter way I can do this? Using `this = x` causes the error `Parsing error: Assigning to rvalue`.

Comment: Why not just send in the current bicycle and have the process return a new bicycle, and repeat that process over and over? You cannot replace an object instance as you've discovered.

Comment: In my real example I have a function similar to `Bicycle.prototype.evolve` so you can neatly call `myBicycle.evolve()` and it suddenly improves. I don't really like the idea of having a seperate function `improveBicycle(bicycle)`.

Comment: `myBicycle = myBicycle.evolve();` — that's a very common pattern with immutable object APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@destroyer answer is good and is the way it should be done. But to answer my question in the way I asked, I ended up doing this:

```
  replace: function () {
    var bicycles = generateRandomBicycles();
    bicycles.sort(function (a, b) {
      return b.score - a.score;
    });

    for (var i in bicycles[0]) {
      this[i] = bicycles[0][i];
    }
  }
```

Which basicly copies all properties. It would also be worthwile to use `hasOwnProperty` in this for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reassign `this`. As @pointy pointed out in the comments, you can create a function which returns a new bike:

```
function Bicycle (wheels, steer) {
  this.wheels = 2 + wheels;
  this.steer = wheels/steer;
}

Bicycle.prototype.replace = function () {
  var bicycles = generateRandomBicycles();
  bicycles.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.score - a.score;
  });
  return bicycles[0];
};

const bike1 = new Bicycle(2, 1);
const bike2 = bike1.replace();
```

You could assign a new instance to the same variable though:

```
let bike = new Bicycle(2, 1);
bike = bike.replace();
```